# Why my app stops when I delete all from EditText?

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to check if the value of EditText is greater than 5, I want the background of the edittext to become RED and it does so but stops when I delete the Text. Please help.

```
  vibration.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            vibration.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            float numV = Float.parseFloat(vibration.getText().toString());
            if(numV > 5){
                vibration.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }else{
                return;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Empty text is not a number giving empty quotes "", enable to parseFloat exception is coming.

Comment: So I should take care of the exception?

Comment: You can check that string is empty or not then parse into float, otherwise return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first check if the the value you are getting from EditText is not null.

```
if(!yourEditText.isempty)
{
//Do your work here
}
else{
//EditText is null}
```